# Imports for a class failing when it is run by a test, python, pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, setuptools

This is my package structure

```
├── src/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── class_1.py
│   ├── used_by_class_1.py
└── tests/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_class_1
```

I have imported my package into test_class_1 using `import src.class_1.py` which lets all the tests run. class_1.py itself imports used_by_class_1.py (and a lot more of my own files that I've left out of the package structure for brevity)

When I run the tests, the import for class_1 allows me to create an instance of it, but when that instance tries to import used_by_class1 it fails. I prepended src. to those imports and the tests worked again, but now the actual program doesn't work and the error message says 'No module named 'src''.

How do I get around this and allow my tests to run without importing all the specific files again, which seems hacky?

It works when I append sys.path in my test code but this again seems hacky, I haven't found a solution which works for both testing and running the code.

Comment: I recommend sharing the actual code from these files. `import src.class_1.py` is not valid python.

Comment: When importing you do not need the `.py` suffix. `import src.class_1` should do the trick.

Comment: Which exact command do you use to run the code?

Comment: I'm using python -m pytest to run the code
I'm not using the .py suffix on import that was a mistake in the question
-- to clarify further if I add the src. prepend the tests work but the script doesn't, when I remove it the tests don't work but the script does

Comment: @Deano Please add more code and correct the import error in your question.